# Launch a QBO3 Task from the main menu

Tags: forms, qbo3

I would like to add a Main Menu option to create a new `Insurance Claim Filing`, where:

- the user should be presented with a custom screen to input required fields
- upon saving a workflow should launch
- the workflow should create a spreadsheet including data entered by the user
- a task should be queued to have a manager review the spreadsheet

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you want to put a cart before the horse. That is, you will render a child object (a `Task`) before it's parent object (`Process`) is created. Leveraging QBO's [related table data pattern](https://github.com/quandis/qbo3-Documentation/wiki/api-overview#related-table-data) and a tiny bit of javascript will bind the `Process`, `Task`, `Document` and `Workflow` together nicely.

By leveraging a QBO's related table data feature,

Consider configuring the following:

- a `Task Template` called `Insurance Claim Data Entry`

  - include whatever user-defined fields you want
  - add a field named `Process_Process`: this will trigger the task to create an `Process`

    - set the `onchange` javascript handler to call `ensureProcess()` (see below)
  - add a hidden field named `Process_ProcessTemplateID`: this will dictate the `Process Template` the `Process` is based on, and in turn, trigger the automatic creation of a workflow
  - add the following javascript function from the `Task GUI Designer`:

```js
function ensureProcess() {
    var task = qbo3.getObject('FormEdit');
    task.options.url = 'Decision/ImportForm.ashx/';
    document.id('FormEdit').getElement('input[name=Object]').value = 'Process';
    document.id('FormEdit').getElement('input[name=Process_ProcessTemplateID]').value = '1';
}
```

- a `Workflow Template` called `Insurance Claim Filing`

  - Step 1: a `Task` named `Insurance Claim Data Entry`
  - Step 2: a `Document` named `Insurance Claim Analysis`
  - Step 3: a `Task` named `Insurance Claim Review`
- a `Process Template` called `Insurance Claim Filing`

  - set it up to automatically launch an `Insurance Claim Filing` workflow when it's created

Tasks can be rendered before their parent exists by calling:

```
/api/ImportFormTemplate/RenderForm?ID={a task template id}
```

You can add to the Main Menu, replacing {a task template id} with the ID of your `Task Template` named `Insurance Claim Data Entry`.

When a user clicks on the Main Menu link to call `ImportFormTemplate/RenderForm`, the `Task` will be rendered. Key concepts to note:

- the `Process_Process` field is required, and a lynchpin to creating the `Task`'s `Parent` object (in this case a `Process`).
- the `Process_ProcessTemplateID` ensures that the newly created `Process` uses the `Process Template` you created
- the `Process Template` you configured will automatically launch a workflow whenever a `Process` based upon it is created
- the `Workflow` will automatically bind to the just-created `Insurance Claim Data Entry` task that kicked the whole thing off, because it's configured with a [`Repeatability`](https://github.com/quandis/qbo3-Documentation/wiki/Patterns#repeatability) of `One per parent`